# Process Memory limits for node.js process in an f1 micro instance in Google Cloud Services?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, v8

I'm trying to get a very basic node.js based project/website up on Google Cloud Services, and am playing with one of their free f1 micro servers. Supposedly these have about 600mb of ram available. `htop` confirms this for me, and also tells me that at idle, it has about 112mb occupied (0K swap by default, fwiw).

One feature of the project I'm trying to get up is that for maximum simplicity and speed, I `require()` a ~75mb json object into memory in my node process, in lieu of a database.

Locally, this is no problem. But when I try to run the app on the f1 micro instance, I get the following error output:

```
ft@instance-1:~/code/zipcode-mapping$ node app.js --max-old-space-size
`<--- Last few GCs --->`
re[2678:0x24bc6b0]      759 ms: Mark-sweep 163.7 (180.4) -> 137.6 (180.4) MB, 19.7 / 0.0 ms  (+ 75.4 ms in 248 steps since start of marking, biggest step 0.8 ms, walltime since start of marking 160 ms) finalize incremental marking via stack guard GC in old [2678:0x24bc6b0]     1483 ms: Mark-sweep 267.9 (307.6) -> 226.3 (306.1) MB, 13.3 / 0.0 ms  (+ 172.3 ms in 260 steps since start of marking, biggest step 5.1 ms, walltime since start of marking 257 ms) finalize incremental marking via stack guard GC in old
<--- JS stacktrace --->
Cannot get stack trace in GC.
FATAL ERROR: NewSpace::Rebalance Allocation failed - process out of memory
 1: node::Abort() [node]
 2: 0x11e7fec [node]
 3: v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(char const*, bool) [node]
 4: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) [node]
 5: 0xad2f0b [node]
 6: v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector::Evacuate() [node]
 7: v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector::CollectGarbage() [node]
 8: v8::internal::Heap::MarkCompact() [node]
 9: v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
10: v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
11: v8::internal::Factory::NewFixedDoubleArray(int, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [node]
12: v8::internal::JsonParser<true>::ParseJsonArray() [node]
13: v8::internal::JsonParser<true>::ParseJsonValue() [node]
14: v8::internal::JsonParser<true>::ParseJsonArray() [node]
15: v8::internal::JsonParser<true>::ParseJsonValue() [node]
16: v8::internal::JsonParser<true>::ParseJsonArray() [node]
17: v8::internal::JsonParser<true>::ParseJsonValue() [node]
18: v8::internal::JsonParser<true>::ParseJsonObject() [node]
19: v8::internal::JsonParser<true>::ParseJsonValue() [node]
20: v8::internal::JsonParser<true>::ParseJsonObject() [node]
21: v8::internal::JsonParser<true>::ParseJsonValue() [node]
22: v8::internal::JsonParser<true>::ParseJsonArray() [node]
23: v8::internal::JsonParser<true>::ParseJsonValue() [node]
24: v8::internal::JsonParser<true>::ParseJsonObject() [node]
25: v8::internal::JsonParser<true>::ParseJsonValue() [node]
26: v8::internal::JsonParser<true>::ParseElement(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSObject>) [node]
27: v8::internal::JsonParser<true>::ParseJsonObject() [node]
28: v8::internal::JsonParser<true>::ParseJsonValue() [node]
29: v8::internal::JsonParser<true>::ParseJson() [node]
30: v8::internal::Builtin_JsonParse(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
31: 0x17b0a8697d
Aborted
```

My question is, how do I determine the process memory limits (and source of that limit) imposed, and if reasonable, how do I expand those?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

V8 developer here. TL;DR: It looks like you simply don't have enough available memory to do what you want to do.

After the last two successful GC runs, reserved memory for the JavaScript heap was at 180MB and 306MB, respectively. The next GC attempt failed because the operating system refused to give another page to the process. It's a safe guess that heap memory consumption was on the order of 450MB at that time, which is approximately what your setup allows.

What do you mean by "a 75MB JSON object"? If the JSON string is 75MB in size, then the parsed object will be quite a bit bigger than that. It probably makes sense to use a database that doesn't need to keep all the data in memory.

Also, `--max-old-space-size` alone does nothing; the flag's purpose is to specify a value, e.g. `--max-old-space-size=1000` for a 1000MB max heap size. However, this is not your problem, as you're not running into the heap limit, which makes sense because the default is more than what your server provides anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Yes, it is actually (I checked again) about a 68mb file, with a `.json` extension. And I solved the issue by doing a filestream line-by-line json parse (I had custom formatted data that made this very simple), but just realized that if I use fs.readFile() I can just json.parse the data that way, and that magically is async in a way that `require()` is not... As a v8 dev, any insight on why `require()` 
 is synchronous? I guess thinking about it perhaps to prevent the requirement that all node code that imports be async...?

Comment: I'm not sure, as `require` is a Node thing that V8 itself doesn't know about. Presumably it must be synchronous because following code can rely on what was `require`d. I'm also surprised that asynchronicity would change anything here, but I'm glad to hear you solved your issue!

Comment: Actually, your last comment is spot on. When I tried running it just async via fs.readFile, it didn't help at all. I was also surprised that would work, but apparently surprise was the correct response... crashed again due to memory shortage on the server. Had to go back to line-by-line parser. Streaming made the difference. In retrospect, this is painfully obvious--of course JSON.parse wouldn't magically notice it was running async now and stream... I now realized what I should be searching for (streaming json parse, not async), and there are many libraries. Oboe.js seems the nicest, perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

You could try creating a swap file (see below).  It will have the effect of creating more memory, but obviously that memory will be very slow to access).

```
if [ ! -f /swapfile1 ]; then
    #the name of the user that runs the app
    USER=myapp 
    #size of the swap file (1Gb)
    SIZE=1048576

    dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile1 bs=1024 count=$SIZE
    chown $USER:$USER /swapfile1
    chmod 0600 /swapfile1
    mkswap /swapfile1
    swapon /swapfile1
    echo /swapfile1 none swap sw 0 0 >> /etc/fstab
fi
```

Then check it worked with `free -m`.  On an f1 micro it should be something like this:

```
$ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            592         210         104           1         277         268
Swap:          1023         112         911
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check [`ulimit`](https://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html) command that it is build in in `bash` and `sh`, in particular:

```
$ ulimit -v
```

The maximum amount of virtual memory available to the process.

There is an interesting article [here](https://www.networkworld.com/article/2693414/operating-systems/setting-limits-with-ulimit.html), notice also the command `$ ulimit -a` that allows you to check all the limits set regarding your project.

Notice that if there is the label "`unlimited`" it means that is limited by the actual machine limits and it will be OOM killed once the machine is running out of resources (if it get selected).